# SAS Modify and/or Replace Master Data with Updated Data

Tags: replace, merge, append, sas, updates

I have two data sets -- a master data set that needs to be periodically updated with the latest data that is contained in a separate data set. I've been playing around with `MODIFY` statements but I'm having trouble completely replacing groups of data. The code below creates two sample data sets:

```
data new;
    input year dqtr age yearq;
    datalines;
    2011    4   43  20114
    2011    4   25  20114
    2013    1   52  20131
    2013    1   45  20131
    2013    2   72  20132
    2013    2   43  20132
    2013    3   93  20133
    2013    3   97  20133
    2013    4   23  20134
    2013    4   37  20134
;
run;

data master;
    input year dqtr age yearq;
    datalines;
    2011    3   94  20113
    2011    3   76  20113
    2011    3   56  20113
    2011    4   43  20114
    2011    4   62  20114
    2011    4   73  20114
;
run;
```

The variable YEARQ is a concatenated variable of YEAR and DQTR. If the YEARQ combination is not in the master data set, it should be appended. If it is within the master data set, then it should replace the entire group. For example, only YEARQ=20114 should be in the final data set. The 3 original 20114 obs should be replaced with the 2 new 20114 obs. The code below almost does what I want, but entire groups of YEARQ are not replaced (it only replaces the first however many observations of that combination found):

```
data master(index=(yearq)); 
    set master;
run;

data master;
    set new;
    modify master key=yearq;
   if _iorc_ =0 then replace;
   else do; 
         _error_=0;       
         _iorc_=0;  
      output;  
      end;
run;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think that's a product of how `modify` works - I don't think you can use it for this purpose (or `merge` or `update`).  I don't have time for a full answer, but the basic issue is the modify (etc.) is not really working the way you think it is.  It's advancing the pointer in the master dataset once each match - so it'll only replace the number it has to replace.  I think you might be able to do a keyed set, but I'd have to think it through more.

Comment: Thanks for you thoughts, Joe. Seems like `modify` or `update` should be able to perform this type of data processing, but I see what you're saying.

Comment: So, I believe I found the appropriate instructions in the documentation on how to do this but it's going to take me a little while to figure out.  Here's the relevant link (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000173361.htm).  Do a search for "Duplicate Index Values".  It says "If there are duplicate values of the indexed variable in the master data set, only the first occurrence is retrieved, modified, or replaced. Use a DO LOOP to execute a SET statement with the KEY= option multiple times to update all duplicates with the transaction value".

Comment: Perhaps someone more familiar with using the DO LOOP / SET process might be able to have a crack it it...That's not really my forte.

Comment: @RobertPenridge Here's a link to the document regarding do-loops when the master and updated datasets have duplicate index values https://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts611.pdf -- link doesn't work so might have to copy and paste. Pages 20-21 seem to have what I'm looking for, but it still was not producing the results I wanted. It'll have to take some tinkering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see your `update` process, essentially what you are trying to do is following

1. If your `new` dataset contains an existing `yearq` value then your are updating it in the `master` dataset i.e. deleting the all the common `yearq` from `master` and appending the new `yearq` from `new` to `master`
2. Also you are appending any new `yearq` to the `master` dataset.

---

Extracting common `yearq`

```
proc sql;
create table common as select distinct(a.yearq) from master as a, new as b
where a.yearq=b.yearq;
quit;
```

Deleting common `yearq` from master

```
proc sql;
create table temp as select * from master where yearq not in(select yearq from common);
quit;
```

Appending `new` dataset to `master` dataset

```
data master;
set temp
    new;
    run;
```

Comment: Thanks @NEOmen -- works great! I've seen the `proc sql` `a.` and `b.` code used before but wasn't quite sure how to use them in combination. This should suffice.

Comment: @Foxer While this may solve the issue you are having I'm not sure it answers the question, which is basically, how to use the `modify` statement in a dataset to update multiple rows.  I think the upvote is warranted but personally I'd be hesitant to mark this as the 'accepted' answer as other people may also have the same problem in the future and come here looking for a solution using data steps and modify statements.  I think this would be the case when datasets are large, and possibly indexed, and the cost of rebuilding them is prohibitive.